# Scala: How to declare two interdependent classes

Tags: scala, class

So basically I'm starting scala and I'm trying to build a simple RPG script to get accustomed to the language. The first problem I encountered is how do I declare a class Character and a class Ennemy, knowing each have methods using instances of the other class as arguments. I haven't encountered this problem in other languages (Or they have a way of saying: Hey I'm using this other class but don't instantiate anything unless you're called), here in Scala I have the following error: not found: type Ennemy.

I guess there is a key word to use somewhere but I just can't find it.

Thanks

Edit: Sorry I didn't incorporate the code, BUt basically I stripped it down to this:

```
class Character {
  var name = ""
  def slain(e:Ennemy) = println(this.name + " has slain ennemy " + e.name)
} 

class Ennemy {
  var name = ""
  def slain(c:Character) = println(this.name + " has slain character " +     c.name)
}
```

And the code still doesn't compile and return the mentioned error.

Comment: You should post enough of the code so that someone can reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did think the description alone is enough, but I follow the advice and add the strict minimum code that doesn't compile. Note I wrote it on a editor and I used :load command in the console.

Comment: Are you doing it in the repl?

Comment: @Su1990 well the code is syntactically correct. I can't pinpoint the problem though, but I would suggest you to use an IDE, e.g., IntelliJ IDEA with the Scala plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the scala repl, you need to define them at the same time to avoid this. This is because each expression is run one at a time, and if you can't reference something that isn't defined yet.

Note that this is not a problem for classes defined in .scala source files.

You can use `:paste` to define multiple things at once.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Character {
  var name = ""
  def slain(e:Ennemy) = println(this.name + " has slain ennemy " + e.name)
} 

class Ennemy {
  var name = ""
  def slain(c:Character) = println(this.name + " has slain character " +     c.name)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Character
defined class Ennemy
```

---

Other notes:

- It's spelt `Enemy`
- You could consider giving both of these a parent class

---

```
trait Entity {
  var name = ""
  def slain(e: Entity) = println(this.name + " has slain enemy " + e.name)
}
class Character extends Entity
class Enemy extends Entity
```

This does mean that characters and enemies can kill their own kind. There's ways you can define it differently to avoid this, but I'll omit them since I think it's more complicated than you need right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :paste is exactly what I'm looking for. I was going to use an IDE because I sort of understood where the problem is, but I really wanted to get this sort out in console before moving on. Sorry for misspelling enemy, I was coding in another language and for purpose of the question I overwrote keywords by their English counterparts and I was in a hurry.